# How come netbeans java profiler crashes with a heap overflow error at ~64mb?

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, memory-management, profiler

I am trying to profile the memory usage of a program, but I keep getting a stack overflow error.

The netbeans memory settings I am using are as follows:

```
-J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m
```

The project memory settings I am using are as follows:

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

[Here is screen shot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?10512ae709.jpg).

I am not sure where 65 mb is coming from.  Can someone please help me?

Thank you,
Grae

PS: netbeans 6.5

Comment: Which version of Java are you using, and how much physical memory do you have in your box?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put `-Xmx` (max. heap size) for Netbeans itself, and the default is 64mb.

Comment: Not exactly. NetBeans adjusts the -Xmx dynamically, depending on your physicall memory (eg. on my 4GB machine it sets max heap to 768M)

Answer (score 0):

This 65M cap is coming from your application. It has nothing to do with NetBeans. You need to increase the max heap for your application in order to get rid of this OOME.

Also, the number of surviving generations is continually growing, indicating a very probable memory leak.

Comment: Do you know of any reference how to do that with Netbeans?  I mean finding a leak.  From my research I think it is a classloader problem.

Comment: Firstly, when your application crashes it should generate a heap dump that can be opened directly in NetBeans or any other heapwalker (MAT, eg.). There you can localize the leaking class.
Then try http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html to pinpoint the allocation place for your leaking instances.